# How do I print original point coordinates if I translate a point outside of a certain square?

Tags: java, oop, coordinate

I'm trying to print the coordinates of a translated point. If the point is translated outside of the 10, -10 range on both the x and y axes, then the original point should be returned and not the translated one. So, for p1 (5,4), if I were to translate it by (7,8), it should return (5,4). I'm having trouble figuring out how exactly to tell Java to print the original point in this case. Do I need to include a Boolean of some sort? Here's what I have so far. (The code is written in German, but "verschiebe" means translate.) Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks y'all in advance :)

```
public class Punkt2 {
private int x;
private int y;

public void setX (int i) {
    x = i;
}
public void setY (int i) {
    y = i;
}
public void verschiebe(int deltaX, int deltaY){
    x = x + deltaX;
    y = y + deltaY;
}

public int getX(){
    return x;
}

public int getY(){
    return y;
}


public static void main (String[] args){
    Punkt p1 = new Punkt();
    p1.setX(5); p1.setY(4);
    Punkt p2 = new Punkt();
    p2.setX(2);p2.setY(1);

    p1.verschiebe(7,8);
    if (p1.getX() > 10 || p1.getY() > 10 || p1.getX() < -10 || p1.getY() < -10){
        System.out.println(new Punkt());
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(p1.getX() + "," + p1.getY());
    }
    p2.verschiebe(3, 2);
    if (p2.getX() > 10 || p2.getY() > 10 || p2.getX() < -10 || p2.getY() < -10){
        System.out.println(new Punkt());
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(p2.getX() + "," + p2.getY());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of doing this would be to check the bounds inside of the translate() method.

For example:

```
private boolean outOfBounds(point, bounds) {
    return (abs(point) > bounds);
}

public void translate(int deltaX, int deltaY) {
    int newX = x + deltaX;
    int newY = y + deltaY;

    if(outOfBounds(newX, 10) || outOfBounds(newY, 10)) {
        return;
    }

    x = newX;
    y = newY;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'm getting a lot of error messages now, though, saying that newX/newY can't be resolved to variables. And similarly, for "point"  I'm getting "bool can't be resolved to a type". Am I just really dumb or do you guys know why this is happening?

Comment: I tried initializing newX and newY as ints, but then outOfBounds doesn't work (again)

Comment: That's mostly me being a little fast & loose with Java. You'll want to declare `newX` and `newY` to `int`s, and return a boolean. Sorry, I don't do java much.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks again! I'm still working out a few kinks, but this has definitely set me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you don't want the point's x or y value to be over 10 or below -10, you can just simply not change the values in the verschiebe method.

Like this:

```
public void verschiebe(int deltaX, int deltaY){
    if(x + deltaX <= 10 && x + deltaX >= -10){
        x = x + deltaX;
    }
    if(y + deltaY <= 10 && y + deltaY >= -10){
        y = y + deltaY;
    }
}
```

Then the point's x and y value will stay the same if they are about to get greater than 10 or lesser than -10. So now in the main class you can just print the point you want to and your verschiebe method will take care that your x and y will always be between -10 and 10.

Comment: Thank you!! I hadn't even considered this as an option, I was so hung up on my booleans. This is quite a clean solution!!

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out how! I realized now that I have to add a separate file in the same package with the "Main" class name. (Noob)

Answer (score 0):

Have a Punkt object be responsible for translating points by returning a "translated" point. It can return self when the translation results in point that is out of bounds.

```
class Punkt {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Punkt(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Punkt verschiebe(int dX, int dY) {
        int newX = x+dX;
        int newY = y+dY;

        if (abs(newX) > 10 || abs(newY) > 10) {
            return this;
        }

        return new Punkt(newX, newY);
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(x + "," + y);
    }

}
```

Would also advise that you have Punk print itself, so your clients can look as:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    Punkt p1 = new Punkt(5, 4);
    Punkt p2 = new Punkt(2, 1);

    p1.verschiebe(7,8).print();
    p2.verschiebe(3,2).print();
}
```

Better still, if the client actually needs to print translated points the above code can be further improved to:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    Punkt p1 = new Punkt(5, 4);
    Punkt p2 = new Punkt(2, 1);

    p1.printTranslated(7,8);
    p2.printTranslated(3,2);
}
```

It's not hard to have Punkt comply to client's needs.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Do you know if there is a way I could go about creating a standalone main class, then, that alleviates the burden from the Punkt class of having to calculate and print?

Comment: Point is a standalone class and is responsible for dealing with point business (translating, printing, etc.)